# getting "insufficient funds for gas * price + value" when using my own BSC full node, at tx signing on web3

Tags: ethereum, binance-smart-chain

I was using the bsc-dataseed.binance.org provider before and was working good, but lately I decided to run my own BSC full node for my project.

When interacting with my BSC full node to send a tx I'm getting this error on the node:

> lvl=warn msg="Served eth_sendRawTransaction"
> conn=CALLERIPADDRESS:59256    reqid=4   t="470.414µs"
> err="insufficient funds for gas * price + value" X-Forwarded-For=nil

The address I want to send the tx from has enough BNB for the fees.

The fullnode is running with the latest versions of geth, and using the latest mainnet files of BSC.

So basically:
-When I run my script to send a tx by using the bsc-dataseed.binance.org provider it's all working.
-When I use my own BSC fullnode as the provider, it's throwing a `insufficient funds for gas * price + value` error

Comment: Is the fullnode connected to the mainnet? Is it fully synced?

Comment: How are you preparing the TX before you send it? This changed some months ago in *geth*. With the London fork your need to prepare you TX a bit different.

Comment: @PetrHejda it's both on mainnet and fully synced. I synced the node with "fast" sync. Still throwing the `insufficient funds for gas * price + value` error